# How can I install an Android app on a desktop OS (Mac/Windows/etc)?

Tags: mac, android, osx-el-capitan

I'm trying to install a chatting app called HelloTalk on my Mac since they don't have a web version. How could I go about doing this?

I am using a Mac. However, if it's possible on PC or some other OS that's absolutely fine as well, as I have Parallels.

Here are the things I've tried doing:

- Using Bluestacks on Mac; it doesn't seem to install properly
- Using Google's ARC Welder app on Chrome. HelloTalk doesn't work and gives me a black puzzle screen
- Trying Chromium OS — I just couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Windows version of Bluestacks via Parallels? Seems dumb that you would need to do so when they explicitly have a Mac version, but it's worth giving it a shot.

Comment: @Thebluefish I haven't, but that seems like a good idea now that I think of it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an android emulator? I think that is exactly what you're looking for. I've had a good experience with an emulator called "andy". I will admit it is time consuming and a fairly large application, but once you get it up your set forever!